# Business name and what visa to use for Canada?

Tags: visas, canada, work, nigerian-citizens

Suppose i register for a business name in Canada,Is it wise i apply for work permit judging that i already have a business name in Canada to run my software engineering Business / Solution development? I am from Nigeria

Comment: I don’t fully understand your question. Are you asking if you are eligible to apply to do business in Canada https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/business-people.html? Or to work in Canada as a business visitor https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/temporary/need-work-permit-work.html?

Comment: i am asking for something quite simple, i do not intend to work in Canada on a visit visa , but then i have a visit visa and i want to setup a business name in Canada so maybe i can come back home and apply for work permit and go back to Canada to run my business, judging that i have setup a business name using service ontario... hence the question

Comment: So, you want to immigrate as a self-employed person? https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/self-employed.html

Comment: @Traveller thats exactly what i was asking.

Comment: In that case, is there something that’s unclear in the information provided on the Government of Canada web page https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/self-employed.html?